# Installing tensorflow on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

After following all the recommended tensorflow install guides, by the time I tried "pip install --upgrade tensorflow" it kept saying "No matching distribution found" and "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions:none)", why does this happen?? Also I'm using Python 3.7!!

Comment: TensorFlow installation guide is currently at https://www.tensorflow.org/install . For help, please provide more details about your software and operating system setup.

Comment: What is the output of `python -V`, `pip -V` and `python -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_supported; print(get_supported()[0])"`?

Comment: well the python version is 3.7.4 and the pip version is 20.0.2,

Answer (score 0):

It has been reported some issues with Python 3.7 and TensorFlow. Maybe installing a specific version could work for you. For example:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15.0
```